# WSDL2JAVA and Heroku

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I'm trying to access an external API in a Heroku environment. I have basically set up all the correct dependencies but now it's throwing the following error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  Unable to load class with name
>   schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sEACC53AB4DE4AB80D192E3C9B6CE210A.TypeSystemHolder

I know I have the generated XSB files and the TypeSystemHolder.class file in my resources directory.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to reference these since I don't know how to do this with Maven.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the "resource" directory where your classes are being generated is a source directory.

Comment: I'm sorry but how would I do that in order for the servlet to pick these up. I've tried adding the resources folder in the build path but that didn't help. Also tried dragging the class files into /target/classes and still nothing

Comment: Sure there is something wrong. Try to run it work without maven and let's see if the error is still there so problem is with maven.

Comment: I have tried it in an Ant build and it all works fine. Heroku handles all the compiling etc. I believe this is the last error before my solution works but I can't get through it.

Comment: So, error is in Maven configuration. Please, show us the Maven configuration.